# Android Voice Call Bluetooth Car Commands

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, voice, headset

I'm wondering how to receive Bluetooth Car / Headset commands in the Android app?

For example, I have a VoIP app and I'm in the voice call connected to a Bluetooth Headset device (specifically my car). And I want to hang up via my car command (End Call), and how do I fetch that event do make some custom action when that is pressed?